# Many errors after update to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3

Hello i'm working on swift 2 with parse then i just updated to swift 3
and i got many errors the app was working perfect. Here is some errors i would get help with:

[image]

Another swift file

[image]

other errors:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How cannot assign that object into `nsarray` and it was working good.

so how could i fix them, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: ok first error solved by cleaning, xcode -> Product -> Clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Swift 3.0 Migration Guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/). It covers everything you need to know about new Swift 3 API changes. Since standard library changed a lot, it is common for third party frameworks to not work fully since they all use standard library as an underlying framework.